# Как задать текст по умолчанию для select через чистый JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть HTML код select:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="select-category-parent_id" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="parent_id">
<option style="display: none;" value="">
Выберите число пж
</option>
<option data-subtext="1">Раз</option>
<option data-subtext="2">Два</option>
 <option data-subtext="3">Три</option>                                           
 </select>
```

Как при нажатии кнопки сбросить значение select чтобы по итогу отобразился текст: "Выберите число пж". Важно, что значение будет передаваться на сервер поэтому value=0 не подойдёт.

Comment: А кнопка то где?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы передавать значения на сервер, обычно пользуются `value` а не `дата-аттрибутами` поэтому я дописал `value` в каждую опцию. Для того чтобы сбросить `select` (мне кажется удобным расположить кнопку сброса рядом), следовательно к селекту можно будет обратиться так `this.previousElementSibling` это очень удобно если таких полей будет много. При желании всю эту разметку можно генерировать из `js`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<select class="selectpicker" id="select-category-parent_id" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="parent_id">
    <option value="">Выберите число пж</option>
    <option value="1" data-subtext="1">Раз</option>
    <option value="2" data-subtext="2">Два</option>
    <option value="3" data-subtext="3">Три</option>                                          
</select>
<button class="btn-primary" id="reset" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.value = ''">❌</button>
<br>
<select class="selectpicker" id="select-category-parent_id_next" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="parent_id">
    <option value="">Выберите число пж</option>
    <option value="4" data-subtext="4">Четыре</option>
    <option value="5" data-subtext="5">Пять</option>
    <option value="6" data-subtext="6">Шесть</option>                                          
</select>
<button class="btn-secondary" id="reset" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.value = ''">❌</button>
```

Comment: В моё случае когда в форме несколько кнопок и пример не работает. Возможно проблема в том, что я использую bootstrap 5 и "bootstrap-select" с полем поиска data-live-search="true" т.к. без этого пример работает нормально.

Comment: Обновил ответ, вставил `бутстрап 5` через `cdn`,  проверьте консоль браузера может что-то пишет? Этот код не должен зависеть от бутстрапа, но возможно мы что-то упускаем, нужно воспроизвести поведение чтобы понять в чем дело.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проблема была в браузере, очистить кэш, всё заработало

Answer (score 0):

Почему `value="0"` не подойдет и причем тут сервер?

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const select = document.querySelector('select')

    select.value = '0'
})
```

```html
<select class="selectpicker" id="select-category-parent_id" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="parent_id">
    <option value="0">Выберите число пж</option>
    <option data-subtext="1">Раз</option>
    <option data-subtext="2">Два</option>
    <option data-subtext="3">Три</option>                                          
</select>
<br><br>
<button>reset</button>
```

Comment: Потому что select находится у меня внутри формы, которую я потом отправляю. Если я так сброшу select, то отправится 0. При этом хотелось бы чтобы элемент-текст по умолчанию не отображался в списке

Comment: @Pahomka используйте `preventDefault` и сбрасывайте `select` уже после отправки, асинхронно